# Client-Server: File transfer from Android to PC connected via socket

Tags: android, sockets, client, transfer

I'm trying to send a picture I choose from the gallery on my phone, and send that picture from the phone to my PC, when I click on the button it should take the picture's path and put it in a file, and transfer it to my PC. I've checked the code on my PC - for both sides - and it worked totally fine.

When I test it out, nothing happens!

Here is the code:

Server side:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class FileServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;

        // create socket
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(1149);
        while (true) {
          System.out.println("Waiting...");

          Socket sock = servsock.accept();
          System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

       // receive file
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Arwa\\Documents\\WebOffice.jpg"); // destination path and name of file
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            // thanks to A. Cádiz for the bug fix
            do {
               bytesRead =
                  is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
               if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end-start);
            bos.close();



          sock.close();
          }
    }

}
```

---

Client side (Android):

```
 package com.arwa.file.send;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SendfileActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("34");
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        System.out.println("36");
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        System.out.println("40");
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                SELECT_PICTURE);
                        System.out.println("47");
                    }
                });
        ;
        System.out.println("51");
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Socket sock;
                try {
                    sock = new Socket("MY_PCs_IP", 1149); 
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");

                     // sendfile
                          File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath); 
                          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                          bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                          System.out.println("Sending...");
                          os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          os.flush();

                        sock.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Path: " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bBrowse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Browse" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When running from the emulator, the IP is different than it is in the "real world"
what is the value of MY_PCs_IP? 10.0.2.2? and the server's IP?

Comment: it's value is my PC's IP, because I'm connecting through WiFi

Answer (score 2):

you have just to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and it will work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying it in emulator on PC try to run the same on a mobile device. Also I have changed the Port number to 8000 instead of using 1149 port.

With these changes the code worked fine for me. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

It aint working cos u havn't reintialized your variable current to 0
It seems your are apending in the subsequent loop without reseting the value. So in my guess it might be causing problem in the second iteration of your execution.