# Android - Sending data from an app to pc via wifi

Tags: android

Wanted to develop an android app to transfer some data to a PC via WiFi.
Both the devices are connected to the same network. I know its a basic server- client program. But can anyone give me links to refer. I have searched but didn't find any complete tutorials. I know how to implement it in c but in android a little help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know how to do it in C, that's enough.  Write the server in C which will run on the PC, and connect to it from your android app.  Since you're writing both sides, the protocol used is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will definitely try

Answer (score 1):

i think this one help you (http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/sending-data-through-wifi-windows-and-receive-it-in-java-android.718060/) and also check this url ([Client-Server: File transfer from Android to PC connected via socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417442/client-server-file-transfer-from-android-to-pc-connected-via-socket))

Answer (score 1):

Little googling would get you a long way. Top two links from the Google which both have code:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html and 
[How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/how-do-i-use-the-simple-http-client-in-android)

Android app acting as a http client needs of course server on the PC, e.g. Apache. Or you can code your own with preferred language.