# Can not send image from android studio to pc using java sockets, filePath returns null

Tags: java, android, sockets

I tried the code from [Client-Server: File transfer from Android to PC connected via socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417442/client-server-file-transfer-from-android-to-pc-connected-via-socket?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the app crashes when sending the image. The Path for the image once the image is selected is returned null. The app is running on an emulator.

My current code is MainActivity:

```
package com.example.floweridentifier;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("34");
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        System.out.println("36");
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        System.out.println("40");
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                SELECT_PICTURE);
                        System.out.println("47");
                    }
                });
        ;
        System.out.println("51");
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Socket sock;
                try {
                    sock = new Socket("My pc's public ip", 800);
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");

                    // sendfile
                    File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath);
                    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                    System.out.println("Sending...");
                    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    os.flush();

                    sock.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.floweridentifier">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FlowerIdentifier">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FlowerIdentifier.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/path" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bBrowse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/browse" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
strings.xml
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Flower identifier</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <!-- Strings used for fragments for navigation -->
    <string name="first_fragment_label">First Fragment</string>
    <string name="second_fragment_label">Second Fragment</string>
    <string name="next">Next</string>
    <string name="previous">Previous</string>

    <string name="hello_first_fragment">Hello first fragment</string>
    <string name="hello_second_fragment">Hello second fragment. Arg: %1$s</string>
    <string name="hello">Flower identifier</string>
    <string name="path">Path</string>
    <string name="browse">browse</string>
    <string name="send">send</string>
    <string name="todo">todo</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Dont use a path that is null. Dont let your app crash to begin with. Did you mean `selectedImagePath` ? If so then why didnt you tell?

Comment: Further your app crashes not with a NullPointerException but with a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
```

replace that by:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

And use `is` instead of `fis`.

Throw away selectedImagePath.